# Get inserted id and specific error message from a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling

I am using dapper to access SQL Server 2016. I have a table called Country with an auto-increment id, a code and a label. To add a new country I have the stored procedure below in my database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewCountry]  
(  
   @Code varchar (50),  
   @Label varchar (50) 
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
   INSERT INTO Country
   VALUES(@Code,@Label)  
END
```

I call the stored procedure from a repository :

```
public class EmpRepository      
{      
    public SqlConnection con;

    private void connection()      
    {      
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConn"].ToString();      
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);      

    }      
    //To Add Employee details      
    public void AddCountry(CountryModel objCountry)
    {     
        try      
        {      
            connection();      
            con.Open();      
            con.Execute("AddNewCountry", objCountry, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);      
            con.Close();      
        }      
        catch (Exception ex)      
        {      

            throw ex;      
        }      

    }
```

If I try to add a country whose code already exists I would like to **throw a specific error message** like "The country already exists" from the stored procedure.

If the country is added I would like to **throw the auto-incremented id**.

So if somebody knows how to send a kind of object with an Id and an ErrorMessage from the stored procedure please tell me.

Comment: Take a look at [RAISERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) which will throw an application exception to the client.  You can specify parameters to insert into the error string, so you could populate that with [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), which will contain the auto-incremented ID.  Although why you'd want to throw an exception when it succeeds is beyond me, you should just return the value.

Comment: Do not use exceptions for things you can easily check in code. Exceptions are desinged mainly for things that you can't control like network errors etc'. Just test if the value already exist in the table. You can use output parameters to indicate if the stored procedure failed or succeded.

Comment: I never said boolean... you can return an int value and a text value. I'm currently not near a computer so I can't show you some cod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zohar Peled already said, I wouldn't throw an exception here.
Just handle the return messages in the procedure.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewCountry] 
(  
   @Code varchar (50),  
   @Label varchar (50),
   @Message VARCHAR OUTPUT,
   @ID INT OUTPUT
)  
AS  
BEGIN 
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Country WHERE Code = @Code)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Country VALUES(@Code,@Label)
        SET @ID = @@IDENTITY
        SET @Message = 'Code inserted'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @ID = 0
        SET @Message = 'Code already exists'
    END

    SELECT @Message, @ID
END
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. May I ask you why you put @@IDENTITY rather than SCOPE_IDENTITY() as @John Wu proposed?

Comment: I wouldn't go with `@@IDENTITY` here. the best option is probably using an output clause with the insert statement. Also, you should both read Dan Guzman's [blog post on conditional insert.](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx)

Comment: Just a habit, in this example there's no difference between SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY as you only modify one table. If you'd modify more than one table and use triggers you gotta be careful. More information here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/